# What is the maximum length of Double.toString(d)?

Tags: java

My experimentation suggests a bound of 24, which is reached by `-Double.MIN_NORMAL`, which results in

```
-2.2250738585072014E-308
```

...but I can't prove it, nor come up with a conclusive reason why no other value should beat `-MIN_NORMAL`.

Comment: Length as in number of characters? What brought on curiosity about this?

Comment: You could try Windows, MacOSX (different processor), Linux on diverse platforms. This is done for Oracle java in `sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.toJavaFormatString(d)` so there is no guarantee. Other than 8 bytes doubles can be approximated sensibly by a limited number of decimals.

Comment: @JoopEggen: The Javadoc of `Double.toString` implies a deterministic algorithm, which should be platform-independent.

Comment: Looking at the (somewhat old) Java source I have, the allocated buffer (inside sun.misc.FloatingDecimal) is 26 characters in size.  So that presumably is an upper limit.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Estimating the size of a `StringBuilder` constructed from various append operations.

Comment: @HotLicks: Do you know which version that is, and where in the source that bound is found?

Comment: @LouisWasserman - I captured the source in April 2009, and the copyright inside Double is 2009.  Closest thing to a version I can find is "jdk7-b54".

Comment: The bound is in sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.java, in the init of `ThreadLocal perThreadBuffer`.

Comment: (Note that `FloatingDecimal` very likely can represent numbers larger than `double`, so it's easy to believe that 26 is larger than needed for `double`.  But, as I say, it's an upper limit.)

Comment: Beware of negative infinity in a JVM configured with Spanish locale, it's `-Extremadamentemierdaenorme`, it's 27-chars

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a 64-bit IEEE-754 float.

The most decimal numbers that can be stored in a 52-bit mantissa is 17 (see [page 4](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/IEEE754.PDF): `ceil( 1 + N Log10(2) )`), so that's 19 characters with the decimal point and negative sign.

The bias is 1023, so the smallest base-2 exponent is 2^-1022, which is around 10^-308, so the longest exponent is 5 characters with the 'E' and negative sign.

19 + 5 == 24

Comment: Do you have a citation for "The most decimal numbers that can be stored in a 52-bit mantissa is 17" ?

Comment: @LouisWasserman - That would be easy to confirm by converting a 52-bit binary number of all 1s to decimal.

Comment: Which you can do with, eg, Windows Calculator, staring with 13 "F" digits in hex, then converting to decimal.

Comment: `System.out.println(Long.toString((1L << 52) - 1).length());` returns 16, or did I translate that wrong?

Comment: The mantissa is base-2 the *right* of the decimal point.  Most significant bit is 1/2, next is 1/4, next is 1/8, and so on.  I've updated my answer with an link to an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

26 seems to be an upper bound, for certain, as follows.

According to GrepCode's version of `FloatingDecimal.getChars`, OpenJDK7 [asserts](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java#910) that the value `nDigits` is at most 19.  Looking at the code, `nDigits` appears to refer to the digits (not the decimal point) of the mantissa: in the above example, `22250738585072014`.  Additional characters, then, include

- a `-` sign on the value as a whole
- the `.` decimal point
- the `E` for the exponent
- a `-` sign on the exponent
- at most three decimal digits on the exponent

... which makes 19 + 7 = 26.

(Arguments for tighter bounds are still welcome.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this bound is correct.  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29) says

> How many digits must be printed for the fractional part of `m` or `a`? There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and beyond that as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type double.

A `double` has an implied integer part (1) and 52 mantissa bits.  Thus, if the base-2 exponent represented by the `double` is 0, so that `x` is a `double` in the range [1,2), then the next higher adjacent `double` is `x` + 2<sup>-52</sup>.  2<sup>-52</sup> is about 2.2204 * 10<sup>-16</sup>.  This suggests that the number of fractional digits needed to distinguish a value from the next adjacent value is 16, i.e. the double adjacent to 1 would be represented as `1.0000000000000002` (15 zeroes).  Since that matches the number of fractional digits in your experiment, it seems very likely that it's indeed the maximum number that would ever be required.  This isn't a rigorous proof, of course; that would take a little more work.